# How to design efficient module for star rating with persistent connection using ZF?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

My CMS based on Zend Framework.
I use star rating for news, articles, blog posts etc. Star rating is a module, so I include it for different content type via inner API which is a wrapper for :

```
$view->action($action, $controller, $module, $params);
```

When I include it to the page with detailed description of news, article ... everything is simple because I call my API method only once, so I make only one call to the DB (MySql).

But I need to include star rating in the items list of the page. There are 20 news on the page. In other  case can be more than 100 items. If I use that structure which I have I will make more than 100 call to the MySql. This is not good, right? How can I design the star rating module in right way?

This is like facebook like-buttons which joins to a different content type on the page.